# Using Facebook share dialog to share video as iframe

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-share

I want to make the Facebook share dialog work in a way that when a user shares the webpage, it appears in the timeline as a video, and when the video is clicked it expands to be an embeded iframe (like what happens when you share a Youtube video).

The open graph meta tags:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="blahblah" />
<meta property="og:title" content="LSK Building" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.example.com/video/some_id" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.example.com/image/some_id/thumbnail.JPG" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="My site" />
<meta property="og:type" content="video" />
<meta property="og:video:type" content="text/html" />
<meta property="og:video:url" content="https://www.example.com/video/some_id/embed" />
<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://www.example.com/video/some_id/embed" />
<meta property="og:video:width" content="800" />
<meta property="og:video:height" content="600" />
```

The share dialog:

```
                window.open('https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share' +
                    '?app_id=' + facebook_app_id +
                    '&href=' + dlink + 
                    '&display=popup' + 
                    '&redirect_uri=' + origin
                    , ''
                    , 'width=0, height=0');
```

It appears correctly (as a video) when shared, but when I clicked the video in the timeline it turns directly into a video element, instead of an iframe. What did I miss?

Comment: You can not embed iframes into timeline – that feature is currently only available to a limited set of Facebook partners. You can only embed flash or mp4 resources, so that they will play in newsfeed directly.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you for confirming this!

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of searching, I find out that probably there is nothing wrong with the open graph tags. The cause should be that Facebook only allow white-list sites to have embedded iframes.

Comment: Have you found a way to share in Facebook an iframe instead of the video element? I'm using the og:video:type as "text/html" and the og:type with "my_namespace:object_type" with an object I created in the app's open graph settings but no luck. My post content is being added as a video element instead of an iframe. I've seen some pages like Sketchfab or helloeko with embedded content. Do I need to submit my app for review or whitelisting?